# How I change or parameterize the HTTP Request Name in Jmeter?

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing

How do I change HTTP request name in each iteration?

Scenario: I am running a single user test for 1000+ iterations, when I run with the help of GUI, I can view the result but sampler name does not change for 1000+ iterations.

My HTTPS request name is as follows:

GetSpace- Next 1000 items

[image]

and when I run the test, my 'View Result Tree' looks as follows:

[image]

I want view result to show result in the following pattern:

GetSpace - Next 1000 item

GetSpace - Next 1001 item

GetSpace - Next 1002 item

GetSpace - Next 1003 item

and so on..

How do I achieve the same? With the help of parametarization or any other method.

I am using the following thread group for the test --single user:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use counter as shown below:-

```
HTTP Request1_100${__counter(,)}
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, tried this its working... how can i increase the counter by 1000 .. ie http Request1_1000, http Request1_2000, http Request1_3000

Comment: I got the answer ..thnx ..just need to add 000 after ...'${__counter(,)}000 '

Answer (score 2):

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you have a special variable which loops like `__jm__<Name of your element>__idx` which holds the iteration number of current [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) derivative (in your case Thread Group)

So if you change your sampler name to look like:

```
GetSpace - Next ${__jm__Next Thread Group(GetSpace)__idx} items
```

You will get an incrementing number depending on current Thread Group iteration:

[image: JMeter Thread Group Iteration]